# Minifying CSS through webpack in one file

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

Using following webpack config I am trying to minify css in entry point entry.js.The entry.js has only require('mystyles.css')

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry:'entry.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

mystyles.css has following css

```
.body { background: #000;  }
```

On running webpack I am getting following error

```
Line 1: Unexpected token .
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Please let me know which loader I have to use to get all .css files into single styles.css file

Comment: How are you pointing to `mystyles.css`? I have documented one possible approach [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/separating-css/). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you..Your Webpack tutorial helped me a lot to understand webpack better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? This will install the `style` and `css` loaders you have referred in your configuration

```
npm i --D css-loader style-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only problem but for starters you do not have an `output` defined in your webpack config object...

You need something like:

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
```

output options tell Webpack how to write the compiled files to disk. Note, that while there can be multiple entry points, only one output configuration is specified.

See the official documentation here:
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration